# Explain the various types of association in ORM and how do you manage the partial changes to a parent objects without modifying the child objects.?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc, orm

What are the various types of association in ORM and how do we manage the partial changes to a parent objects without modifying the child objects ?

Comment: This question is too board. Please kindly see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258589/breaking-down-too-broad-and-trying-to-understand-it) on why and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Agreed, too broad... And it sounds suspiciously like a homework question.